# How to access element from nested child component

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to access elements inside a child element from parent like the following example code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `<child></child>`
})
export class Parent implements AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChildren('element') viewChildren: QueryList<ElementRef>
    @ContentChildren('element', {descendants: true}) contentChildren: QueryList<ElementRef>

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log(this.contentChildren)
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.viewChildren)
    }
}
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: `
        <div #element>Div1</div>
        <div>Div2</div>
        <div #element>Div3</div>
    `
})
export class Child {}
```

My actual results are empty arrays, but i would expect an array with **Div1** and **Div3**. What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

My real problem is:
I have a component that knows when to append/remove a css class in some elements. This elements may be in its own component or its child, grandchild and so its on.
In other words, what i am trying to accomplish is a *angular way* to do the following line:

`let elements = document.querySelectorAll("div[element]")`

Comment: contentchildren is something inside ng-content :)

Comment: @ABOS yeah, but i had to try =P

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain `@ViewChildren` first; it means that you have a child component in the **HTML** template and you wanna reach it in the **component.ts** file.
For instance:

```
<child #nested> </child>
```

So, you will be able now to reach this component selector is the **ts** file using `nested` element name; like this:

```
@ViewChildren(‘nested’) child: Child;
```

You can make the same declaration for the required elements in the child component, like this:

```
@ViewChildren(‘element1’) element1: ElementRef;
```

And now it will be defined in the child and you can reach it from `child`variable:

```
this.child.element1
```

And so on.

BTW, I don’t know if you can use one ref for more than element.
But that should work.

Comment: Your solution works, but i was looking for something that get elemet1 directly from parent. In real code i may have more depth than code that i post. But thx anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put ViewChildren logic into child component and emit changes to parent component, if the code is under your control.

In child component,

```
@ViewChildren('element') 
set viewChildren( v: QueryList<ElementRef>){
  this.viewChildrenChanges.emit(v);
}

@Output() viewChildrenChanges = new EventEmitter();
```

In parent component template,

```
<app-child name="{{ name }}" (viewChildrenChanges)="show($event)"></app-child>
```

This is something I can think of based on your current description/requirement.

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adbo1h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

btw, I have removed duplicate `#element` on child divs as angular complains about that.

Comment: The code is under my control, but i have more than one child, and the parent has to get some elements from its grandchild. I edit my question, maybe has this aditional information explains better what i trying to accomplish.